# Ant script with PMD check not recognizing JDK 1.8

Tags: ant, java-8, pmd

> Hi All,
>
> I am currently working on a legacy system and moving the current
>   version of jdk to 1.8. Earlier our ant script was like this to apply
>   the pmd checks :

```
<target name="check-pmd-writable-force" unless="git.scm">
        <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpath="${basedir}/tools/pmd/pmd-java-4.2.2.jar"/>
        <pmd rulesetfiles="${basedir}/tools/rulesets.xml" targetjdk="1.5">
            <formatter type="html" toFile="${basedir}/pmd_report.html" toConsole="false"/>
            <formatter type="text" toConsole="true"/>
            <fileset dir="${workmanager.dir.src}">
                <patternset refid="sources-no-tests"/>
                <custom classname="com.osm.tools.ant.AntWritableSelector" classpath="${workmanager.ant.tools}"/>
            </fileset>
        </pmd>
    </target>
```

> But as I am moving our application to jdk 1.8 pmd is showing some
>   error/warning which I need to resolve. So I cahanged the ant script
>   with the latest change below:

> But doing so gives me the below error:

```
The targetjdk attribute, if used, must be set to either '1.3', '1.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7' or 'jsp'
```

> I searched a lot and tried adding the below line after taskdef line
>   but end up getting another error.

```
<sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>
```

> Any idea how to make my above configuration for pmd to work with jdk
>   1.8

Comment: Which version of [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) do you use? Maybe it is too old to support the Java 8 syntax (e. g. Lambdas).

Comment: I changed to PMD 5.8.1 but got , pmd doesn't support the "targetjdk" attribute

Comment: Yes, the Ant task has changed, use `<sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>` instead: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/usage/ant-task.html

Comment: This is what I have changed: in above config: <sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>
        <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpath="${basedir}/tools/pmd/pmd- 5.8.1.jar"/>

Comment: But I see this error: Problem: failed to create task or type sourceLanguage

Comment: `<sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>` must be a child element of `<pmd>`.

Answer (score 3):

your problem lies on the used PMD version.

```
classpath="${basedir}/tools/pmd/pmd-java-4.2.2.jar"
```

4.2.2 is a **very old** version (May 2008, a full 6 years before Java 8 was even released). Java 8 support was added on PMD 5.1.0.

You should always use the latest PMD version, to make sure you have:

- all the new rules
- all bug fixes
- all performance improvements

The latest PMD version is 5.8.1. Version 6.0.0 is very close to being released.

An equivalent ant configuration for current PMD versions would be

```
<path id="pmd-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/tools/pmd/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="check-pmd-writable-force" unless="git.scm">
    <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="pmd-classpath"/>
    <pmd rulesetfiles="${basedir}/tools/rulesets.xml">
        <sourceLanguage name="java" version="1.8"/>
        <formatter type="html" toFile="${basedir}/pmd_report.html" toConsole="false"/>
        <formatter type="text" toConsole="true"/>
        <fileset dir="${workmanager.dir.src}">
            <patternset refid="sources-no-tests"/>
            <custom classname="com.osm.tools.ant.AntWritableSelector" classpath="${workmanager.ant.tools}"/>
        </fileset>
    </pmd>
</target>
```

Comment: Doing so I ended up having : pmd doesn't support the "targetjdk" attribute. Where I mentioned targetjdk=1.8

Comment: Yes, that attribute was removed a long time ago, when PMD ceased to be a Java-only analysis tool, and was replaced by the `sourceLanguage` element. I just provided an example ant config for you, but please, refer to [the documentation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.8.1/usage/ant-task.html)